# Existence of a continuous ergodic dynamical system for a given distribution?

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

It seems to me that given a distribution (which is well-behaved), there should be at least *an* ergodic dynamical system that its time average would create this distribution. Is this question already answered in the literature? or is it just too simple?

Most of my search results talk about the measure that's the result of an ergodic system, and not the other way around. Could somebody shed light on this please?

**EDIT**: Based on the comment of @WillSawin I am adding that, let's assume the distribution is defined over $\mathbb{R}^n$, or maybe more generally over a Riemannean manifold, with a compact support. Additionally the dynamical system has a flow which is a smooth function of time.

Comment: What kind of measure spaces are you looking for distributions on? For many notions of "distribution" and "nice" there is a theorem of the form "there is a single distribution that every nice distribution is equivalent to" so the result you're looking for would be true, but basically trivial.

Comment: @WillSawin, thanks very right point. I am phrasing this question from pure intuition. I made corrections. I hope the new form makes sense.

Comment: If the support has two disjoint components then the flow I don't think the flow can be a smooth function of time and also be ergodic since the flow would not be able to mix the two components. So there must be some criteria.

Comment: Instead of looking at flows, maybe it would be simpler to ask about a discrete dynamical system generated by a continuous map?

Comment: You will probably need a absolutely continuous measure w.r.t to Lebesgue.

Comment: @WillSawin, I guess I assume the measure has a connected support.

Comment: For the uniform measure on $S^2$, you may run in trouble finding a continuous time dynamical system it is ergodic for, because of the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: @WillSawin,  I don't see why a slowly raising dynamical system from southern pole to the northern pole (northern pole is where the vector field vanishes and southern pole is the opposite) finally stopping at the northern pole doesn't do the job, especially with the comment I added under MartinMW's answer.

Comment: Slowly raising from the north pole to the south pole doesn't sound like it has an invariant measure supported on the whole space, not to mention being ergodic.

Comment: To precise Will Sawin's remark, Poincaré--Bendixson's theorem implies that the ergodic invariant measures of a flow on $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb S^2$ are supported by cycles or fixed points, so many ``natural'' measures cannot be ergodic invariant measures.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $S^1$, and $\delta_P$ be a point-mass at a point $P \in S^1$.

Then there is no flow on $S^1$ whose time averages lead to $\frac{1}{2}(\mu + \delta_P)$. (Consider the orbit of $P$.)

This distribution seems like it should count as "well-behaved." Its support is connected, and both $\mu$ and $\delta_P$ themselves arise as time-averages (by a rotational flow, and a flow to an attracting fixed point, respectively).

You can generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by looking at an embedded $S^1$, and generalize to continuous maps by replacing the rotational flow with an irrational rotation.

Comment: Thank you, great example.  Do you mind if I update my question by asking that for the given measure with support $M$, and  $\delta>0$ there exist another measure such as $\mu'$, where $\mu'$ with support $M$ which is the time average of a dynamical system, and additionally $\|\mu-\mu'\|_{KS}<\delta$. I feel your example is in line with how one makes a counter-example to convert Boltzmannean ergodicity to von Neumannean ergodicity. No?

Comment: It might be simplest to ask a new question, and make reference to this one as motivation. But feel free to add an update if you want (it's your question!), just make it clear what the old version of the question was, so this answer and other comments still make sense.